# network does not support ENS (operation="getResolver", network="maticmum", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.7.2)

Tags: solidity, polygon, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm trying to interact with a contract deployed on Mumbai testnet but getting this error everytime

```
network does not support ENS (operation="getResolver", network="maticmum", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7289:19)
    at Logger.throwError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7298:16)
    at Web3Provider.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9901:16)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7984:24)
```

i asked about this to chatgpt he gave me this statement
** the error you encountered suggests that the specific operation you are trying to perform, such as retrieving the resolver contract with a "getResolver" operation, may not be supported on the Mumbai testnet.**

im trying to interact with the contract but getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to resolve a non-address string into an address on a network that doesn't support ENS.

For example `vitalik.eth` ENS name, but also incorrectly formatted address such as `const address = "0x1231231231231231231231231231231231231231 ";` (with a space at the end).

So to resolve the error, you need to pass a correctly formatted address.